# SpaCy - where are terminologies defined?

Tags: spacy

There are terminologies such as **GPE**, **ROOT**, **LOC**, but where are they defined in the [SpaCy document](https://spacy.io/)?

ChatGPT says:

> In SpaCy, GPE stands for "Geo-Political Entity". It is a named entity label used to identify geopolitical entities, such as countries, cities, and states.

But how do people understand and identify the definitions of terms in SpaCy?

[image]

Comment: They are not part of the API.  They are simply named entity labels used by the various corpora that spacy uses.

Answer (score 2):

Seems information are here and there, and not available in SpaCy, it seems.

- [Explorations in Named Entity Recognition, and was Eleanor Roosevelt right?](https://towardsdatascience.com/explorations-in-named-entity-recognition-and-was-eleanor-roosevelt-right-671271117218)

```
PERSON:      People, including fictional.
NORP:        Nationalities or religious or political groups.
FAC:         Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.
ORG:         Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.
GPE:         Countries, cities, states.
LOC:         Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water.
PRODUCT:     Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (Not services.)
EVENT:       Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.
WORK_OF_ART: Titles of books, songs, etc.
LAW:         Named documents made into laws.
LANGUAGE:    Any named language.
DATE:        Absolute or relative dates or periods.
TIME:        Times smaller than a day.
PERCENT:     Percentage, including ”%“.
MONEY:       Monetary values, including unit.
QUANTITY:    Measurements, as of weight or distance.
ORDINAL:     “first”, “second”, etc.
CARDINAL:    Numerals that do not fall under another type.
```

- [NER annotation scheme: GPE vs. LOC](https://support.prodi.gy/t/ner-annotation-scheme-gpe-vs-loc/2913/3)

```
GPE: geopolitical entities, e.g. everything with a governing body like cities and countries. Examples: "Germany", "Buenos Aires".
LOC: everything else that's a physical location or area, like "Kalahari Desert" or "Silicon Valley"
```

ROOT looks to be the root node of a dependency grammar syntactic dependency structure, although not 100% sure as I cannot find a definition in SpaCy documents so far.

- [Dependency grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar)

> When one is striving to identify the root of a given phrase, the word that is most responsible for determining the distribution of that phrase as a whole is its root.

[image]